Getting image to reach end of webpage
I am creating my very first website and I am struggling to have the image (which is in the header section within a div container) to reach the very edge of the webpage so there is no gap visible. It is not stretching wide enough to fill the space entirely. I've attached a screenshot but unsure if you can view it. (https://i.sstatic.net/nqLp4.png). I've attached a second image of the code I'm using in HTML.
(https://i.sstatic.net/NpBEq.png)
I tried Googling and Youtube videos but couldn't find any answers.

Either your <div></div> container has a margin or padding value assigned to it that needs to be removed or you need to reset the default HTML margin/padding settings by adding body { margin: 0; padding: 0; } to your stylesheet.

It's a good idea to learn to use your browser's devtools inspect facility. This will show you exactly what CSS is being applied and from where. In this case look for margins e.g. on the body and other elements.

It's a common issue in CSS where the body of the webpage has a default margin. This default margin is causing your image not to reach the edge of the webpage. You can remove this default margin by adding the following CSS rule:
body {
    margin: 0;
}

This rule sets the margin of the body element to 0, effectively removing the gap you're seeing. Add this rule to your CSS, and your image should now stretch to the edges of the webpage. If you're still facing issues, please provide more details or code snippets for further assistance.

This problem is most likely due to default browser styles. Use this tool.
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/
